# Changing array values to certain values/interval?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, rotation

I rotate different arrays (`dtype`: `np.float32`) of shape `3x3`, `5x5`, `31x31`, ... using [scipy.ndimage.rotate](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.rotate.html). The input arrays always have a `sum <= 1.0` and in most cases the sum is equal to 1.0 minus a very small epsilon. The minimum of these arrays is always `>= 0.0`.

My expectation was that I should always get arrays which values are in the interval `[0.0, 1.0]` as the result of `scipy.ndimage.rotate`, but sometimes I get very small negative values as a minimum, like `-1.0755285551056204e-16`. I guess this appears due to floating point number inaccuracies?!

However, I would like to squash the output arrays' values into the expected interval `[0.0, 1.0]` (while also ensuring a sum <= 1.0). How can I achieve this as fast as possible (computation time)?

Something like a [softmax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Softmax_function) would not be good idea, since it rescales the array's values in a way (exponentially) that already high values get even higher.

In some rare cases the returned array of `scipy.ndimage.rotate` also had a sum > 1.0 (positive float imprecision?!), thus I think simply using a [sigmoid function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigmoid_function) would not be good idea, because I would just scale the values independently, not checking for the sum being <= 1.0.

Comment: That small negative value is essentially 0. Are you not okay with applying `max(0, value)` on your matrix? The sum will still be 1 minus a small epsilon.

Comment: If you subtract the smallest value of the array (this would be adding the abs if the smallest value is <0), and then divide all values by the sum, you should get all values >=0 and the sum=1. But there are other ways to achieve this goal, so what you do will depend exactly on what your goals are.

Comment: @tom10 this sounds like a reasonable & fast way. It would also ensure that the values do not lose their relation between each other, right?

Comment: @pault this way I would lose the relation between the numbers?! Because I would just "cut out" the negative epsilon from the lower end of the interval. The operation should affect all values, in order to keep the relation of value to another.

Comment: In choosing between these and possible other approaches, you need to carefully think through what your ultimate goal is, or not.  For example, if you prefer my soln because it more accurately deals with `e-16` size errors, you probably shouldn't be using `float32`. That is, @pault soln is probably good enough and is very likely faster. In the end, it's usually fairly difficult to deal with these small calculation errors in a way that's better than just ignoring them.

Comment: True, but I guess I have to use your solution, even when inaccuracies like `e-16` are very small. Although it happens very rarely sometimes I get a positive inaccuracy, like a sum of 1 + some `e-16`. This error can not be corrected with `min(0, array)`, since the values only have a sum > 1.0, but are always < 1.0 themselves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rotation involves spline interpolation. Interpolation of values between 0 and 1 does produce values outside of interval [0,1] sometimes. As long as these deviations are small (and they should be small), there is no need to think hard about them; [numpy.clip](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.clip.html) will do a quick job.

```
image = np.clip(image, 0, 1)
```

As for the sum - the sum of array is not expected to be same after rotation. If `reshape=False` is used, a part of the image goes away. If not, the new image still won't have exactly the same values as the old one, since they were re-interpolated to a different grid. The sum can go up or down.

Since the requirement of sum being <= 1 is not geometrically natural, there is no geometrically natural way of ensuring it. So you can do whatever  algebraic manipulations you want. Like this:

```
if image.sum() > 1:
    image /= image.sum()
```